# How to call method using windows service, and manage all related event handler like before run, after run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf

Net Masters,

We design an ASP.NET MVC web application, this application integrated with thierd party to exchange some information, the process of preparing the required information take around 3 minutes, I want to handle this by allow end user to click s button then to show status of transfer info "waiting for send" during this a record in DB will be created, database table will consedered as a queue for set of tasks, Now we need a tool to keep verify if there is a task in the queue to perform, if it found a record then it will perform set of operation to prepare info to be sent to external entity, we have an idea to create custom wcf service to handle this senario, but before start this development effort I need to ask if there is any tool that could achive this rather than develop it from scratch since we have set of case to handle (for example if third party not accessable then the service need to keep attempt to deliver the required info).

Comment: [Quartz.Net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) is a scheduler.

Comment: Unfortunately this question is off-topic, as it is very broad and opinion-soliciting (lots of ways to handle scheduling, polling, queueing, etc.). Also, tool/product/framework recommendation questions are off topic as well.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe hangfire.io is "your tool".

As David wrote: there no special "tool". Only a lots of ways to handle your dev task with projects like quartz.net, hangfire, rabbitMQ, ...